# cin is not accepting input - waits infinitely for user to enter something

Tags: c++

[image: See the cursor in console window. I have pressed enter so many times. It just goes]I have small C++ program which performs few functions based on input provided by user from a display list. It displays a list of functions that this program will execute (right now there is only 1 function just for showing). User enters an integer denoting the function number in the display list. Accordingly proceed. I am facing problem with user entering an integer. It just does not proceed even after entering integer and pressing enter key; and waits infinitely. Nothing happens after entering some integer for 'Select your choice: ' and pressing enter. It just goes on to next line waiting for some input.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

static void reverseString(string &str);
static void swap(string &str, int i, int j);

int main() {
    int choice;
    do {
        cout << "1) Print k lines from file" << endl;
        cout << "11) Exit" << endl << endl;
        cout << "Select your choice: "; // Program infinitely waits here for user.
        cin >> choice;

        if(choice == 1) {
            string word;
            cout << "Enter a word: ";
            cin >> word;
            cout << endl << "You entered '" << word << "'." << endl;
            reverseString(word);
            cout << endl << "Your reversed string is '" << word << "'." << endl;
        }
    } while(choice != 11);
    return 0;
}

static void reverseString(string &str) {
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while(str[j] != '\0') j++;
    j--;
    while(j > i) {
        swap(str, i, j);
        i++;
        j--;
    }
}

static void swap(string &str, int i, int j) {
    char temp = str[i];
    str[i] = str[j];
    str[j] = temp;
}
```

Please help me. I cannot find the cause. I tried cin.clear() and cin.ignore() but nothing helped.

Comment: If `cin` is not accepting data, why is your code example not `int main() { int choice; cin >> choice; }`? This suggests you are missing something in your question.

Comment: How do you know it's not working?  Have you run it in a debugger to see exactly what is happening?

Comment: Yes. After placing breakpoint at cout << "Enter your choice", the debugger prints out that line on console. After entering a digit say 1, the debugger seems to be hanged. After terminating the debugger, streambuf file is opened automatically.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to diagnose your problem for sure but it seems likely that cinn is accepting data and you are supplying the wrong data. The way your program is written, any  data other than 1 or 11 won't be processed, indeed it will appear as if cinn is not working. If your problem persists even for the input of 11 than something is wrong with your compiler.

Comment: It does not work even after entering any digit, not only 1 or 11.

Comment: That's the idea. The way you write it, it will only work for 1 and 11, not for anything else. Did it work for 11?

Comment: No, it did not work for 11. I am attaching screenshot how it looks after entering 11. It just does not proceed.

Comment: Are you sure its not proceeding or could it be it is exiting

Comment: Yes I am sure, because I manually have to stop its execution.